# How do I pass back a string and a boolean in one function in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

So i have this function

```
    public bool FileExists(string path, string filename)
    {
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, "pool");
        string[] results = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, filename, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
       return (results.Length == 0 ?  false : true);
    }
```

And it returns true or false on whether a file is found in a directory and all its subdirectories...But i want to pass the string location as well

Here is how i call it

```
            if (FileExists(location, attr.link))
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo("string the file was found");
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Maybe change to a list or array ...any ideas

Comment: Would returning the string for a match or null for no match work? Otherwise you can return a simple struct with a bool and a string, or if it comes to it accept an out-type string argument to return the value in - neither are particularly pretty though.

Comment: Are you potentially returning more than one file, that matches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean you just wish to return all of the occurrences of where the file was found?

You can just do:

```
public static string[] GetFiles(string path, string filename)
{
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, "pool");
    return System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, filename, SearchOption.AllDirectories);   
}
```

And use like so:

```
var files = GetFiles(location, attr.link);

if (files.Any())
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Rename the method to `TryFindFile` and provide with the signature thusly:

```
public bool TryFindFile(string path, string filename, out string location)
```

The method returns `true` if it found the file, and sets `location` to the location, otherwise it returns `false` and sets `location` to `null`. You can type `location` as a `string[]` if there are multiple locations.

Comment: +1. I like that, and it should be familiar to those who use the various framework Try methods

Comment: Good point RichardOD, and good answer Jason. This should be "the answer", although Dave makes a good point below that the file could be found in multiple places. Maybe your Jason's answer should type the `out` var to `string[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Add out parameter that you need.

```
bool FileExists(string path, string filename, out string somthElse)
{
   somthElse = "asdf";
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an output parameter (out string[] results) to the method and keep the method or you can change the method and return the array of results (and check the true or false in the caller).

The cheaper thing to do is to add an out parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Various ways- return a struct or a class with two fields, use [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword modified, use a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `out` parameter?

```
public bool FileExists(string path, string filename, out string location)
{
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, "pool");
    string[] results = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, filename, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var doesExist = (results.Length == 0 ?  false : true);
    location = fullPath;//or whatever it is
}
```

You can then call it thusly

```
if (FileExists(path, filename, out location))
{
    //location now holds the path
}
```

More info on `out` parameter can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).